# Add Sharepoint codes/tags in html master page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-designer, master-page, custom-masterpage

SP newbie here. Just wanna ask if I can add Sharepoint tags in the HTML master page (.html  file). I am quite confused on where should I put my codes. Most articles I found on the web say I should edit the master page. Is it referring to the .html file or the .master file?

Also, is it better (or not) if I break the association of the .html file and the .master file? I think I'll be working on lots of customizations. Should I decide to break it and work directly with the .master file, can I delete the .html file?

**UPDATE** I am using Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise Edition

Comment: Please state your SharePoint version. This should be mandatory. There is a boatload of differences between 2013 and earlier version. I assume you are on 2013, so the answer provided by @MikeTran13 misses your question totally. Things are different in 2013.

Comment: @teylyn The version tags should only be used in questions with problems related to a specific version (not earlier, not future versions). See discussion in meta http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/has-the-policy-for-version-tags-changed. In this case it feels valid though :)

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can do that. You can customize your master page by Sharepoint Designer or you can create a project with master page file. In that, you can customize the master page as you want and create a feature for that. Your master page will be applied to your site when the feature is activated.

You can refer to these links:

- [Create Custom CSS and Master Page in SharePoint](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/create-custom-css-and-master-page-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)
- [SharePoint Custom Master Page](http://joshuaorimogunje.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/how-to-create-custom-master-page-for-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010/)